# For Google API Access, can I create multiple Client IDs for the same Android package name?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I am following the Quickstart guide here to get Google Drive integration with my android app: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android .

So I created two Client IDs using the debug and release SHA1 fingerprints for the same package name. The API Console allowed this, but I was wondering since I created the Client ID with the debug key SHA1 fingerprint, will the Google OAuth2 server accept authentication request coming from my release apps?

By the way, I am using Google Play Services API to request auth token, so there's no way to specify the 'Client ID' string shown in the API Console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to specify the Client ID in your code because your credentials are matched using the package name/SHA1 fingerprint pair, which is unique.

As you generated credentials for both the debug and release certificate, your requests will be authorized correctly as long as your app uses either of those with the package name specified in the APIs Console.